# Select a month and show respective mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, drop-down-menu, echo

i am new to php. I am trying to create a drop down showing months and showing values from database according to month selected. Below is the code i've created and tried first-

```
<?php
$_e1 = System::getUser()->get('earnings_jan');
$_e2 = System::getUser()->get('earnings_feb');
$_e3 = System::getUser()->get('earnings_mar');
$_e4 = System::getUser()->get('earnings_apr');
?>

<div class="user_content">

<select id="month" name="month">                      
<option value="0">--Select Month--</option>
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
</select>

if(value == 1)
{
echo $_e1;
}
else if(value == 2)
{
echo $_e2;
}
else if(value == 3)
{
echo $_e3;
}
else if(value == 4)
{
echo $_e4;
}
</div>
?>
```

I have ended PHP twice but started once. If i start PHP again it shown internal server error. Drop down is showing but all the if statements are also showing. I am unable show selected.

Then -
I have also tries this one -

```
    <?php
$_e1 = System::getUser()->get('earnings_jan');
$_e2 = System::getUser()->get('earnings_feb');
$_e3 = System::getUser()->get('earnings_mar');
$_e4 = System::getUser()->get('earnings_apr');
?>

<div class="user_content">

<select id="month" name="month">                      
<option value="0">--Select Month--</option>
<option value="1">Jan</option>
<option value="2">Feb</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
</select>

if(value == 1)
{
<?php echo $_e1; ?>
}
else if(value == 2)
{
<?php echo $_e2; ?>
}
else if(value == 3)
{
<?php echo $_e3; ?>
}
else if(value == 4)
{
<?php echo $_e4; ?>
}
</div>
?>
```

This code calls the data from sql but shows all if statements. Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `if` statement needs to be inside a PHP code block. Try `<?php if($value==1) { echo $_e1; } else ... ?>`. Also, where did `value` come from? It's not a variable (no `$`) and it doesn't seem to have been assigned a value anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to place every PHP statement between the `<?php ?>` marks.
2. Your `$value` have to be assigned with something. You have to place that `<select>` into a `<form>` with a submit button and make it to post to the same page, then retrieve the posted data from `$_POST`, like this:

   ```
   $value = $_POST['month'];
   ```

   The `month` key comes from the name of the `<select>`. Also you should validate *everything* that comes from `$_POST`.

   Now assuming that your `$_e1`, `$_e2`, etc variables are correct, you can print them.
3. You should convert those `if()`s to a [`switch` statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). That makes the code shorter and more readable. But actually you could just use this:

   ```
   if (($value >= 1) && ($value <= 4)) {//If you really have only 4 months.
       echo ${'_e' . $value};
   }
   ```
4. You should use [`for()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loops and/or [`foreach()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) constructs instead of manually setting everything line by line. This also applies to your `System::getUser()` lines. You should also consider using [arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).
5. You should give better names for your variables. Names like `$_e1` aren't very meaningful.
6. Try to learn the basics of the language before you create something big.

Comment: I got it.Thanks for your help. May God Bless Us All.